# Any open source Migration tools that save Site as Template?

Tags: content-migration, save-as-template, open-source

We've deployed software in our SharePoint environment that leverages publishing.  With publishing enabled you lose the ability to save Site as a Template.  Are there any open source tools (perhaps migration tools) that perform this same function?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about the tools. However, If you are ready to write some code, you can use sharepoint pnp site provision to create and apply the template to the site. Though you will have to write some code, but it will be minimal. With this You can also serialized the template for future use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking something like this, right? http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2017/10/29/save-publishing-site-as-template-the-right-way-using-pnp-provisioning/

Comment: Kasper...This is fantastic.  Thank you once again!

Comment: Kasper...The example given was for Office 365...This will work for SharePoint 2013..yes?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but publishing is fairly old, at least since SP2013 so I would think so

Comment: Please  let us know if it works 

Comment: kasper.  I can confirm that PnP Remote provisioning works for On-Prem and SharePoint online.  
"To use the PnP provisioning engine on-premises, you need to have at least the SharePoint 2013 March 2015 Cumulative Update installed."
Thanks again!

Comment: Great, happy to hear that it works 

Answer (score 0):

1- Open the site with SharePoint Designer

2-In the ribbon go to Site Options

3-Locate the option SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled and modify the value to true

4-Since the site template is disabled in the Publishing sites the option Save Site as Template is not available in the Site Settings you will need to navigate to the page directly: http://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx

5-Provide all the details and click OK after a couple of minutes you will have the WSP site template generated

Note: If you have apps downloaded from the store they could prevent you to save the site as a template if you are facing this scenario you will need to uninstall the apps first.

6-Open the Solution Gallery and click in the template name to download the wsp file containing the site template

Reference [Here](http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2016/10/05/save-publishing-site-as-a-template/)

Comment: This won't be supported by Microsoft, if that matters to you.